# Netsh command not working in C# to capture trace

Tags: c#, netsh

```cs
using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    string cmd = "trace start capture=yes";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
    process.Start();

    // Synchronously read the standard output of the spawned process.
    StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
    output = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // Write the redirected output to this application's window.
    //Console.WriteLine(output);

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

The above code gives me following error ***"The following command was not found: trace start capture=yes"***

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem - it works fine for me...

Comment: @JonSkeet I am able to run the command from netsh.exe in windows. In above code if I replace string cmd = "interface show interface"; it works, but only capture trace is not working.

Comment: Is the program being run under an account which doesn't have the path to netsh.exe in its environment variables? Although why it doesn't complain that it can't find netsh.exe, I don't know.

Comment: @AndrewMorton suspected the same but other commands are working

Comment: Did you try "C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe"?

Comment: @bourne Initiating a trace session usually requires local admin access, make sure the hosting application launches elevated

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am running above console application in VS 2015 as a administrator

Comment: @AndrewMorton C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe doesn't work too.

Comment: There is no problem finding and running `netsh` here. The error message "The following command was not found: trace start capture=yes" is produced by `netsh` itself. You get the same error running `netsh banana`. Verify that `netsh trace start capture=yes` works if you try it from a command line, outside C#. You may just have a version of Windows where this isn't supported yet -- try `netsh ?`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert other commands are working fine from console application. Also I am able to run same command by manually opening netsh.exe and pasting the same command in cmd window. It starts capturing trace successfully.

Comment: Ah, but you know which version of `netsh` does *not* have `trace`? The 32-bit version. Try `c:\windows\SysWOW64\netsh trace`. So you are most likely compiling your app as 32-bit or as AnyCPU with "prefer 32-bit" checked, and file system virtualization gives you the *other* `netsh` when it goes to `system32`. Compile your app as 64-bit.

Comment: @JeroenMostert aah, perfect....that worked, went to VS project properties->PlatformTarget->Disabled Prefer32bit. THANK YOU :)